# MVC 3 Razor model not updating: 'Model' does not contain a definition for 'PropertyName'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, model

Very simple MVC application, with one model, one loosely typed view and controller sending 
`List<Model>` to the view through `ViewBag`.

All was working fine until I updated the model. Now I get 'Model' does not contain a definition for 'PropertyName', Tried rebuilding the application and cleaning the temp folder.

What do I need to clean up to get this recompiled properly?

**~Edit**: Property that cannot be found was added to the Model not removed. And I'm trying to use this new property in the View.

**~Edit**:
Model:

```
public class App
{
    public String title { get; set; }
    public String featured { get; set; }
    public String subtitle { get; set; }
    public String thumb { get; set; }
    public String logo { get; set; }
    public String web { get; set; }
    public String email { get; set; }
    public String phone { get; set; }
    public String download { get; set; }
    public String body { get; set; }
    public List<String> tags { get; set; }
    public List<String> features { get; set; }
    public List<Highlight> highlights { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
ViewBag.apps = (from xml in XmlResources.Root.Descendants("app")
                        select new App
                        {
                            title = xml.Element("title").Value,
                            featured = xml.Attribute("featured").Value,
                            subtitle = xml.Element("subtile").Value,
                            thumb = xml.Element("thumb").Value,
                            logo = xml.Element("logo").Value,
                            web = xml.Element("web").Value,
                            email = xml.Element("email").Value,
                            phone = xml.Element("phone").Value,
                            download = xml.Element("download").Value,
                            body = xml.Element("body").Value,
                            tags = (from x in xml.Descendants("tag") select x.Value).ToList(),
                            features = (from x in xml.Descendants("feature") select x.Value).ToList(),
                            highlights = (from x in xml.Descendants("highlight") select new Highlight { type = x.Attribute("type").Value, src = x.Attribute("src").Value }).ToList()
                        }).ToList();
```

View:

```
@using eduApps.Models;
 @for (var i = 0; i < ViewBag.apps.Count; i++)
 {
  @{ if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.apps[i].web))
                   {
                        <span>Web:</span><a href="@ViewBag.apps[i].web" title="@ViewBag.apps[i].title">@ViewBag.apps[i].web</a>
                    }
  }
}
```

Error:
'eduApps.Models.App' does not contain a definition for 'web'

Comment: Looks like you still use this `PropertyName` somewhere in the Views.

Comment: Could you provide model-, view- and controllercode?

Comment: When I had this problem, I created a new view file, copied the code across, and deleted the old file.

Comment: @Zabavsky: please see 1st 'Edit'

Comment: You may want to remove the `;` in your razor script, I think it will show up in your resulting output now. I've seen some `;`'s pop up in my own outputs occasionally, usually because of the C# habit of adding it to the end of my statements.

Comment: @Tobias: Please see 2nd 'Edit'

Comment: @René Wolferink, Thanks for the tip, I thought they are required in Imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try casting to your class `(ViewBag.apps[i] as eduApps.Models.App)` when using it, as there is no strong typing here MVC will see your `ViewBag.apps[i]` simply as an `object` and not an `App` which indeed won't contain any of your defined properties:

```
@{ 
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty((ViewBag.apps[i] as App).web))
    {
        <span>Web:</span><a href="@(ViewBag.apps[i] as App).web" title="@(ViewBag.apps[i] as App).title">@(ViewBag.apps[i] as App).web</a>
    }
}
```

I don't know where your `App` class definition is located so you'll have to replace `Namespace.` with the appropriate name space, or add a `using` directive to your name space at the top of your view.

**EDIT** - sorry just noticed you've already added a `using` to your view of `eduApps.Models`. I've amended my answer.

Comment: I tried that, so now I get this error during compilation. If i go to definition of the App by hitting F12 it brings me to the App[from metadata] file in temp folder which is old Model. deleting this file doesn't help.

Comment: @SergejPopov It's bring up the metadata file for an old version of `App` do you mean? Have you tried cleaning your project and doing a full rebuild to generate new assemblies?

Comment: yes meta of the App is old version, I tried: "Rebuild Solution" and "Rebuild Web Site", I don't have "clean solution" option.

Comment: @SergejPopov ah you're using a web site and not a project, in that case go to the root of your application and manually delete the assembly with your class definition in from the `\bin` folder then rebuild your solution.

Comment: Thx, for helping me with this, There is only one relevant dll in \bin folder eduApps.dll if I delete it I get compilation error: Could not load type 'eduApps.MvcApplication'. C:\tfs\Projects\eduApps\Global.asax

Comment: @SergejPopov Are your class definitions AND website code contained in  the same assembly? Unfortunately you're into a whole new issue here all I can really suggest is that if your class definitions are contained in an external assembly, then make sure you've re-compiled this assembly and have added a reference to it in your website via visual studio. Otherwise, I'd suggest starting a new project and move your code across. Something has gone wrong with the structure of your website within visual studio.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Will keep trying.

Comment: Not exactly the solution but helped me to understand few things. Marking as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What I don't understand is why u use ViewBag instead of Model.

Your ControllerMethod should look like:

```
public ActionResult Foo(){

   IList<App> model = 
   (from xml in XmlResources.Root.Descendants("app")
                    select new App
                    {
                        title = xml.Element("title").Value,
                        featured = xml.Attribute("featured").Value,
                        subtitle = xml.Element("subtile").Value,
                        thumb = xml.Element("thumb").Value,
                        logo = xml.Element("logo").Value,
                        web = xml.Element("web").Value,
                        email = xml.Element("email").Value,
                        phone = xml.Element("phone").Value,
                        download = xml.Element("download").Value,
                        body = xml.Element("body").Value,
                        tags = (from x in xml.Descendants("tag") select x.Value).ToList(),
                        features = (from x in xml.Descendants("feature") select x.Value).ToList(),
                        highlights = (from x in xml.Descendants("highlight") select new Highlight { type = x.Attribute("type").Value, src = x.Attribute("src").Value }).ToList()
                    }).ToList();


   return View(model);
}
```

And your view should do the following;

```
 @model IList<App>
 @foreach(App app in Model){
     @{ if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(app.web))
        {
           <span>Web:</span><a href="@app.web" title="@app.title">@app.web</a>
        }
     }
 }
```

Hth Tobi

Comment: I too wondered this, where possible you should always strongly type your views. I just assumed there was some valid reason on their side of using the `ViewBag`.

Comment: Valid point, not sure why I didn't use the Model, Didn't solve the problem though. Thanks anyway.